# JLabel/JPanel positioning issues. (GridBagLayout)

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Having small issues on the positioning of my `JLabel` components.

Code:

```
    public class delete {


    public static void main(String[] args){
         GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Adding the JPanels. Panel for instructions
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        //JLabel for the Instructions.
        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html> Instructions: Type in the grades you’ve received, along with the weights they’ll have in the determination of your overall average. <br> After you press ‘Calculate’, the results will show your average so far. <br> Every grade you enter must be a non-negative number, and every percentage/weight you enter must be a positive number :)</html>");
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        panel.add(label, gbc);


        //JLabel1 for Assingment/Grade/Weight(Percent)
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html><pre>Assingment\t\t\t\t\tWeight\t\t\t\t\tPercentage</pre></html>");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(label1, gbc);


        //New frame set
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grade Calculator");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(750,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);



    }


}
```

Now right now this positions `JLabel` (`label`) at the top of the frame which is what I want. The problem is `JLabel` (`label1`) I want `label1` to be Slightly below label.

If I set `gbc.gridy = 0`, `label1` shows on top of label making both of the separate collide together.

When I set `gbc.gridy = 1`, `label1` goes all the way to the bottom of the frame.

Now I want `label1` just to be slightly under label however I cannot use floats with `gridy`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gbc.weighty = 1;` is causing the component to be provided with all the remaining space left over after all the components are laid out.  Instead of providing `label` with this constraint you should give it to `label1` only

When you don't provide a `gridx`/`gridy` to component, `GridBagLayout` places the component next to the last component, since no other components have been added, `label` is placed at the top, but you're also supplying a `gridx`/`gridy` of `0` to `label1`, which is placing at the same location.

Instead, place `label` at `0x0` and `label1` at `0x1`

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html> Instructions: Type in the grades you’ve received, along with the weights they’ll have in the determination of your overall average. <br> After you press ‘Calculate’, the results will show your average so far. <br> Every grade you enter must be a non-negative number, and every percentage/weight you enter must be a positive number :)</html>");

gbc.gridwidth = 2;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.gridy = 0;
panel.add(label, gbc);

//JLabel1 for Assingment/Grade/Weight(Percent)
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html><pre>Assingment\t\t\t\t\tWeight\t\t\t\t\tPercentage</pre></html>");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
gbc.weighty = 1;
panel.add(label1, gbc);
```

You can also effect the position that a component will align to within it's cell through the use of the `anchor` property.

[image: GridBagLayout]

Have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for some more details

Without knowing "exactly" what you're doing, I might suggest also having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. All the time I ALWAYS use the Java Tutorials before asking a question here but I can never fully understand it till someone explains on here. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello, there is something else I'm having an issue with. Will you be able to help me out pleasE?

Comment: @bob9123 I typically provide links to other tutorials, docs or supporting documentation, as you shouldn't take my word for things ;).  If you're having more issues, perhaps consider asking another question, simply provide a link back to this one as a reference point for people who might not have read this one yet ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416519/small-gui-issue-i-cannot-fix-jtextfields Link to new problem. Thanks for the help again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//JLabel for the Instructions.
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html> Instructions: Type in the grades you’ve received, along with the weights they’ll have in the determination of your overall average. <br> After you press ‘Calculate’, the results will show your average so far. <br> Every grade you enter must be a non-negative number, and every percentage/weight you enter must be a positive number :)</html>");
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
panel.add(label, gbc);


//JLabel1 for Assingment/Grade/Weight(Percent)
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html><pre>Assingment\t\t\t\t\tWeight\t\t\t\t\tPercentage</pre></html>");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
panel.add(label1, gbc);
```