# Small GUI issue I cannot fix. JTextFields

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel, jtextfield, gridbaglayout

Small error I can't manage to do. So right now my program GUI looks like this:
[image]

Now there is a TextField under the 'Mark' column were the user can input their data. I also want the same for the weight section were I want to insert a TextField right under 'Weight' column.

However when I try and put in a TextField, both the the Textfields turn like this when the window is small: 
[image]

and this when the window is enlarged:
[image]

**How can I make it so that there is a textfield under Mark AND Weight?**

Code:

```
public class Gradeanalysis implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
     GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    //Adding the JPanels. Panel for instructions
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //JLabel for the Instructions.
    JLabel label = new JLabel("<html> Instructions: Type in the grades you’ve received, along with the weights they’ll have in the determination of your overall average. <br> After you press ‘Calculate’, the results will show your average so far. <br> Every grade you enter must be a non-negative number, and every percentage/weight you enter must be a positive number :)</html>");
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(label, gbc);


    //JLabel1 for Assingment/Grade/Weight(Percent)
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html><pre>Assingment\t\t\t\t\t  Mark\t\t\t\t\tWeight</pre></html>");
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    panel.add(label1, gbc);

    //JLabel Numbers for the number list of assingments at the side.
    JLabel numbers = new JLabel("1");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    panel.add(numbers, gbc);        

    //JTextfield for Mark
    JTextField mark = new JTextField(2);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(mark, gbc);


    //JTextfield for Weight
    JTextField weight = new JTextField(2);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    panel.add(weight, gbc);


    //New frame set
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grade Calculator-- ");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(750,700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);




}
```

}

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Change `frame.setSize(750,700)` to `frame.pack();`

Comment: Myself, I'd use a JTable

Comment: Is that as complex as Gridbaglayout? After this I have to do things like getting all the inputs and manipulating the number of assignment rows that are displayed on the screen.

Comment: A JTable has its own complexities but it is the best Swing tool to use to display tabular data, which is what it looks like you are trying to do here.

Comment: Would it allow me to see the inputs/do calculation with them and also let me limit how many rows I can put on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Grade Calculator]

1. I don't know where your main method is, but you **must always** start a Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  The invokeLater method puts the creation and execution of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. When I use the GridBagLayout, I use the addComponent method I created to create a unique GridBagConstraints for each Swing component.  I don't like to remember defaults.
3. The order of the JFrame methods is **extremely important**.  Memorize the order of the JFrame methods in this example.
4. I put the instructions in a JTextArea.  This way, the instruction text splits based on the size of the JTextArea.  There's no need to hard code the line breaks with HTML.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GradeAnalysis implements Runnable {

    private static final Insets normalInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
    private static final Insets finalInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GradeAnalysis());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grade Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Adding the JPanels. Panel for instructions
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        // JLabel for the Instructions.
        JTextArea instructionTextArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        instructionTextArea.setEditable(false);
        instructionTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        instructionTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        instructionTextArea.setText(getInstructions());
        JScrollPane instructionScrollPane = new JScrollPane(instructionTextArea);
        addComponent(panel, instructionScrollPane, 0, gridy++, 3, 1,
                finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        // JLabels for Assignment/Grade/Weight(Percent)
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Assignment");
        label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, label1, 0, gridy, 1, 1, finalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Mark");
        label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, label2, 1, gridy, 1, 1, finalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Weight");
        label3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, label3, 2, gridy++, 1, 1, finalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        // JLabel Numbers for the number list of assignments at the side.
        JLabel number = new JLabel("1");
        number.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, number, 0, gridy, 1, 1, normalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        // JTextfield for Mark
        JTextField mark = new JTextField(20);
        mark.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, mark, 1, gridy, 1, 1, normalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        // JTextfield for Weight
        JTextField weight = new JTextField(20);
        weight.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, weight, 2, gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        return panel;
    }

    private String getInstructions() {
        return "Instructions: Type in the grades you’ve received, along with the weights "
                + "they’ll have in the determination of your overall average. After you "
                + "press ‘Calculate’, the results will show your average so far. Every "
                + "grade you enter must be a non-negative number, and every "
                + "percentage/weight you enter must be a positive number :)";
    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets,
            int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Saved me hours of researching/developing. Now for this program I have a screen before this one that asks the user how many assignment they want to use. With this method is there a way to change the amount of rows  of assignment/mark/weight? For example say the user entered 3 there will be three different rows of assignment(1,2,3)/mark and weight ( the program will expand accordingly) . You don't have to make new code to address this, just want to know if this will work.

Comment: @bob9123: Yes, you can make a user defined number of rows.  The most user friendly way would be to get the number from a primary screen, then show the calculation screen.  Take a look at the [card layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: A helper method isn't necessary, because it's not necessary to create a new GridBagConstraints for each add.  You can use the same GridBagConstraints repeatedly, changing only one or two values as necessary, since the add method will clone the constraints internally.

Comment: @VGR: You're right.  The computer has no problem with one GridBagConstraints.  People, on the other hand, seem to have a great deal of difficulty remembering the GridBagConstraints state, myself included.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you

1. Don't use `setBounds(...)` on any component or GUI
2. Same for `setSize(...)`
3. Instead nest JPanels each using its own layouts to achieve a pleasing and easy to manage layout and GUI.
4. Consider putting your intro text into a JTextArea. If you want it to look like a JLabel, you can take out the background color and borders.
5. Best of all would be to display the tabular data in a JTable, and for that you'd want to create your own table model, one based on the AbstractTableModel and that uses an Assignment object for each row.

---

An example *without* the JTable:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GradeAnalysis2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private static final String DISPLAY_TEXT = "Instructions: "
         + "Type in the grades you’ve received, along with the "
         + "weights they’ll have in the determination of your "
         + "overall average.\n"
         + "After you press ‘Calculate’, the results will show "
         + "your average so far.\n"
         + "Every grade you enter must be a non-negative number, "
         + "and every percentage/weight you enter must be a "
         + "positive number :)";
   private JTextArea displayArea = new JTextArea(5, 50);
   private GradeTablePanel gradeTablePanel = new GradeTablePanel();

   public GradeAnalysis2() {
      displayArea.setText(DISPLAY_TEXT);
      displayArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      displayArea.setLineWrap(true);
      displayArea.setEditable(false);
      displayArea.setFocusable(false);
      displayArea.setBorder(null);
      displayArea.setBackground(null);

      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      centerPanel.add(gradeTablePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      centerPanel.add(Box.createGlue(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(centerPanel);

      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AddAssignmentAction("Add")));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(displayArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension sz = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return sz;
      }
      int height = Math.max(sz.height, PREF_H);
      return new Dimension(sz.width, height);
   }

   private class AddAssignmentAction extends AbstractAction {
      public AddAssignmentAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnenomic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnenomic);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         gradeTablePanel.addAssignment();
         gradeTablePanel.revalidate();
         gradeTablePanel.repaint();
      };
   }

   private class GradeTablePanel extends JPanel {
      private int count = 0;

      // parallel collections -- a bad kludge. 
      // a table model would make this much cleaner
      private List<JTextField> marks;
      private List<JTextField> weights;

      public GradeTablePanel() {
         setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
         JLabel assgmntLbl = new JLabel(Assignment.ASSIGNMENT, SwingConstants.CENTER);
         assgmntLbl.setFont(assgmntLbl.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
         JLabel markLbl = new JLabel(Assignment.MARK, SwingConstants.CENTER);
         markLbl.setFont(markLbl.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
         JLabel weightLbl = new JLabel(Assignment.WEIGHT, SwingConstants.CENTER);
         weightLbl.setFont(weightLbl.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));

         add(assgmntLbl, createGbc(0, 0));
         add(markLbl, createGbc(1, 0));
         add(weightLbl, createGbc(2, 0));
      }

      private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
         GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
         gbc.gridx = x;
         gbc.gridy = y;
         gbc.gridwidth = 1;
         gbc.gridheight = 1;
         gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
         gbc.weightx = 1.0;
         gbc.weighty = 1.0;
         gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
         return gbc;
      }

      public void addAssignment() {
         count++;
         JLabel countLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(count));
         JTextField markField = new JTextField(2);
         JTextField weightField = new JTextField(2);

         add(countLabel, createGbc(0, count));
         add(markField, createGbc(1, count));
         add(weightField, createGbc(2, count));
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GradeAnalysis2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new GradeAnalysis2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}


class Assignment {
   public static final String ASSIGNMENT = "Assignment";
   public static final String MARK = "Mark";
   public static final String WEIGHT = "Weight";
   private String assignment;
   private int mark;
   private double weight;
   public Assignment(String assignment, int mark, double weight) {
      this.assignment = assignment;
      this.mark = mark;
      this.weight = weight;
   }
   public String getAssignment() {
      return assignment;
   }
   public void setAssignment(String assignment) {
      this.assignment = assignment;
   }
   public int getMark() {
      return mark;
   }
   public void setMark(int mark) {
      this.mark = mark;
   }
   public double getWeight() {
      return weight;
   }
   public void setWeight(double weight) {
      this.weight = weight;
   }


}
```

Comment: Oops -- too late (work gets in the way). Oh well, 1+ to Gilbert's decent answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the minimum, expected and maximum sizes for each JTextField like so:

```
JTextField t = new JTextField();
t.setMaximumSize(MAX);
t.setMinimumSize(MIN);
t.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

Where MIN and MAX are a Dimension Object, and the inputs to set bounds are `int`

Comment: No, don't do this. The column property ought to be adequate. He's setting his GUI's size, something that will futz up his layout. The component itself and the layout managers should be responsible for component and GUI size.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - if you have a better solution then please add it as an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is your answer 10min supposed the answer you're adding? When I use pack method it messes everything up by starting the window in a very small size.

Comment: @bob9123: no, there's more to it than that.