# How do I save multiple JTextField to MySQL values in order? Can this be done?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I got a program that asks the user to enter values into a range of different `JTextField`s.

An image  of this looks like this:
[image]

When the user clicks save I want it to be saved as a format Mark...Mark then Weight...Weight. So in this case 60,90,40,60.

I'm assuming for this you will need a for loop for the `JTextField` that saves them onto a MySQL db? I can do this.

**My problem is how do I change MySQL to support this? Do I have to make multiple tables or can I use the same table? Right now my sql code is like this:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SavedCalculations;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SavedCalculations(Mark FLOAT, Weight FLOAT);
```

**To my knowledge I'm assuming I can only input one value. So one Mark and one Weight value? How can I solve this problem so I can put many Mark/Weight values in order?**

**I also need to consider an easy way of retrieving this data from mysql and putting it back to their positions in their designated `JTextFields`.**

```
public class GradeInputs extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


private JTextField textfield; //TextField from Initialinput which records the number of assignments.
private JTextField mark = null; //Firstly initializes the JTextField mark so it can work with Action Listener.
private JTextField weight = null; //Firstly initializes the JTextField weight so it can work with Action Listener.

//Making the object for that variable.
public GradeInputs(JTextField textfield){
    this.textfield = textfield;
}

//These are there representations of borders of a container. NormalInsets = JTextfields. Final = JLabels.
private static final Insets normalInsets = new Insets(10,10,0,10);
private static final Insets finalInsets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);


//This is the method that gets the input from user from the Initialinput GUI.
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try{
        String userinput = textfield.getText(); // Gets the textfrom the field.
        int userint = Integer.parseInt(userinput); // Turns the string into an Int.
        if(userint>25){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter an Integer less than 25!.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        //Sets the basis of the frame.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(userint));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }catch(NumberFormatException k){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a non-negative Integer!");
    }
}
//Initialsing the JPanels. userint is part of the method signature (a parameter). This determines the layout of the GUI for this class.
private JPanel createMainPanel(int userint){

    int gridy = 0;

    JTextField[] markTextFields = new JTextField[userint]; //Holds individual data. Size depends on the number of assignments.
    JTextField[] weightTextFields = new JTextField[userint];
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    //Adding the JPanels. Panel for instructions
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());



    //JLabels for Assignment.
    JLabel assignmentlabel = new JLabel("Assignment");
    assignmentlabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, assignmentlabel, 0, gridy, 1, 1, finalInsets,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    //JLabel for Mark
    JLabel marklabel = new JLabel("Mark");
    marklabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, marklabel, 1, gridy, 1, 1, finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    //JLabel for Weight.
    JLabel weightlabel = new JLabel("Weight (Percent)");
    weightlabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, weightlabel, 2, gridy++, 1, 1, finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    //JLabel Number for the number list of assignments at the side.
    gbc.gridy = 3; //gbc.gridy at y position 3 all the time so it correctly aligns.
    for(int i = 1; i<=userint; i++){
        String stringnumbers = String.valueOf(i); //This is responsible for making the for loop a String which can be listed down. I get strings of the incrementing for loops.
        JLabel number = new JLabel(stringnumbers);
        number.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, number, 0, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
    }

    gbc.gridy = 3;
    //JTextfield for Mark
    for(int i=0; i<userint; i++){
        mark = new JTextField(20);
        markTextFields[i] = mark; //For each mark in the JTextField they get inserted into markTextField[i] with a for loop.
        mark.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, mark, 1, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    }

    gbc.gridy = 3;
    //JTextfield for Weight
    for(int i=0; i<userint; i++){
        weight = new JTextField(20);
        weightTextFields[i]= weight;
        weight.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        addComponent(panel, weight, 2, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    }

    JButton savebutton = new JButton("Save");
    addComponent(panel,savebutton,3,gbc.gridy++,1,1,normalInsets,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);



    //Reset JButton which resets all JTextFields.
    JButton resetbutton = new JButton("Reset");
    resetbutton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, resetbutton, 3, gbc.gridy++, 1,1,normalInsets,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);


    //JButton for sending all the data from this class to the next class that calculate the data.
    JButton computebutton = new JButton("Compute");
    computebutton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, computebutton, 3, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);


}


//Method that is responsible for the object making of JLabels/TextFields/JPanels.
private void addComponent(Container container, Component component, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets, int anchor, int fill ){
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D,1.0D,anchor,fill,insets,0,0);
    container.add(component,gbc);
}
```

Update---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SavedCalculations;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SavedCalculations(Profile VARCHAR(50),Mark FLOAT, Weight FLOAT);
INSERT INTO SavedCalculations(Profile,Mark) VALUES('FirstYear',70.44);
INSERT INTO SavedCalculations(Profile,Weight) VALUES('FirstYear',69.42);
```

Comment: Either have a "predeance" value in the table or store all the values in a single row

Comment: Any guides on how to implement a predeance value? I was thinking of going ahead of putting all values in a single row but do the number of values have to be defined before I can allow this? Because I have rows that can contain different number of values. Is that a problem?

Comment: In case of a single row, then yes, you will need columns for those, but it's the easiest as you define the precedence yourself.  If you have a single value per row, you will need two things, a `group` value, which allows you to identify the groups of values and a `precedence` value which determines in what order they should be listed in, which you could sort on

Comment: So I will need a column for Mark and Weight? Each row will contain on of each of those values and using a precedence value I can determine the order they come out of mysql? Also a group value to make sure they are all from the same calculation?

Comment: That would be my basic idea ;)

Comment: If your program will display many such rows, you will likely be better off using a JTable instead a grid of JTextFields.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay thanks, got a long night ahead.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I already have implemented JTextFields, changing a JTable will make me have to change my whole program which will a long time

Comment: It was just a suggestion, one that you may feel free to follow or not, as your need and wishes dictate.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have made changes to mySQL according to your instructions. I'm still unsure what you mean a standard int with auto increment or something like that? Updated me post with my latest mysql code. Profile as 'group value?'

Comment: @bob9123, `changing a JTable will make me have to change my whole program ` - which you could have done 10 days ago when the suggestion to use a table was first made: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31416519/131872. A JTable is far easier to work with. For example the data will be in numeric format already. `So in this case 60,90,40,60.` why in that format? I would store 3 values: assignment, mark and weight. You can get the data back in rows which is much easier to work with. And rows of data can easily be added to a JTable.

Comment: @camickr understand that a JTable will be easier to work with and in the future if I do anything like this I will use a JTable however, I've already made progress with this and if I have to go back and change everything and make sure everything work it will take me a lot of time (literally days) due to me having no experience in this. Also I'm sure that with the method I'm doing can achieve the goals I want.

Comment: Assuming you only want to list ALL the weights/marks, then you only need some kind of precedence value in order to maintain the order. You could look into an auto incremental value in MySQL (no real experience with that)